# Newly defined alias not working inside a function (zsh)

Tags: function, alias, zsh, operator-precedence

I tried to define and then use an alias inside of a function in zsh.  It doesn't work.  Why on earth not?  And can I get around it?

```
% cat > test
alias_problem () {
  alias hithere="echo Hi there!"
  hithere
}
^D
% source test
% alias_problem
alias_problem:2: command not found: hithere
% hithere
Hi there!
% wtf?
zsh: no matches found: wtf?
```

Ideally, running alias_problem would print out `Hi there!`  Can anyone explain what's going on?  And is there a way to get around it?

Background:  I want to make a function that will create several aliases and then run one of them.  Something like

```
myfuncA () {
  alias alias1=...
  alias alias2=...
  alias1
}
```

so that I can set up an environment with several commands.  I'll have a second function that will toggle the aliases to a different set.

Should I just be using functions?  Is there any reason to use aliases over functions in zsh anyway?  I would like to know what's going on, just to know how to avoid it in the future.

Thanks :)

--Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mentioned in `man zshmisc` under ALIASING:

> There is a commonly encountered problem with aliases illustrated by
>   the following code:
>
> ```
>           alias echobar=’echo bar’; echobar
> ```
>
> This prints a message that the command echobar could not be found.  This happens because aliases are expanded when the code is
>   read in; the entire line is read in one go, so
>          that when echobar is executed it is too late to expand the newly defined alias.  This is often a problem in shell scripts,
>   functions, and code executed with ‘source’ or ‘.’.
>          Consequently, use of functions rather than aliases is recommended in non-interactive code.

I *think* that the problem is that the body of your function is stored as a single line (implicitly as `alias hithere="..."; hithere`), so that the same situation as encountered in the quote above applies.

Comment: So you (and zshmisc) are saying that if echobar were already defined, then `ls; echobar; ls` is expanded to `ls; echo bar; ls` and THEN executed?

I missed that; thanks.

Comment: Right. The code is read when the function is defined, so nothing undergoes alias expansion when the function is *called*, although the alias is defined for code that is read following the function call. It's a little more clearly seen with this: define `foo () { bar; }`, then define the alias `alias bar="echo foo"`. Calling `foo` still produces the command not found error, because no alias expansion is performed on the body of the function when the function is called.